# Moving from windows to ubuntu 12 linux for development

Tags: linux, ubuntu

i am java developer, i used fully windows for development, now i want to move to ubuntu 12 for development, i even found difficult when i tried to install new software, its not that easy to install new software in Ubuntu ?.

1) In windows we just click it for installing software, so am i need to know commands in linux ?

i am almost new to linux,

2) what are the basic thing i need to know about linux(ubuntu) or where can i get info 
(FOR DEVELOPMENT).

```
    I used  

         1,Eclips

         2,Jdk

         3,Sts (spring IDE)

         4, Android SDK, etc....
```

now i need these development tools for ubuntu, can i get these tools in one place.

THANKS

Comment: Have you done *any* research, or are you waiting for us to pull out our spoons?

Comment: Ubuntu uses software packages. Using the command: sudo apt-get install <name of package> you'll be able to install most of the software you need. I suggest getting well trained in using the command line. You can search for the name of the package. Unfortunately, you'll need software that is not available in Debian packages. You'll have to search for instructions on how to install the specific software in that case.

Comment: yes doing, but i think this is best place

Comment: -1 for asking a question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can install Eclipse from apt-get: **sudo apt-get install eclipse**.
2. You can install the open source variation of the Java JDK with: **sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk**.
3. Never used it, but I've seen many places where it has been installed in Ubuntu.
4. As for Android, you can install it pretty much the same way as you would in Windows.

   1. Download it from: [Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
   2. Get a dependency for 32 bit libs (if you are running 64 bit): **apt-get install ia32-libs**
   3. Extract the tar file anywhere, and use the terminal 'cd' command to go into the 'tools' directory, then Use **./android** inside.

Etc. As for all around Ubuntu help I urge you to visit http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=310 for Ubuntu programming or just the forums in general for Ubuntu help. You can also get a bunch of packages by searching apt-get with **apt-cache search -what you want-**, which can be handy for finding packages.

Comment: Absolutely. And in case @Viswa dislikes the command line, he can use the *"Software Center"* to browse and install all standard packages (Eclipse etc.) in a nice graphical way. I believe he will find a shortcut in the ridicoulus dock at the left of his screen... However, developing without the command line is a bit like eating without a plate.

Comment: No problem. @amon I agree that he can use Software center, but to be honest it would be easier to browse via apt-get due to the Software Center being dreadfully slow.